How to prevent sql injection when using spring data couchbase with Query annotation?
I am having Controller, Service, Repository kind of Spring web project having enterprise couchbase server as DB, I am using spring-data-couchbase for querying data of couchbase, and I am using @Query Annotation to put custom queries.
Recently I came across a case where, i am having @Param String name as method param. in one of the request, i got name param’s value was having escaped double quotes, which has broken my couchbase query which is complex query but its simple representation is below
@Query(
"""
#{n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{n1ql.filter}
AND name = "#{#name}" AND …
""")

→ I want to sanitize value having escaped double quotes in “#{#name}”, using standard owasp library, and I do not want to do custom regex things.
Ref.
https://www.couchbase.com/forums/t/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-when-using-spring-data-couchbase-with-query-annotation/39223

You need to use proper parameterization, not escaping. And the SELECT part must be in a whitelist.

@Charlieface can you please elaborate more, if possible point me to some sample implementation example

Use $name (no quotes) instead of "#{#name}". Using #{#name} is handled by the Spring SPEL parser and is simply a string replace. $name (or $1) is a n1ql query parameter and there is no possibility for sql injection.
